# Select second child image & apply style to it jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is the div structure

```html
<div class="amlabel-div categoryp_productflag_image_615448">
  <a href="https://www.web.com/bat-wing-sunglasses-black.html">
    <img src="https://www.web.com/skin/frontend/web/web/images/category/wph.png" alt="">
    <figure class="hidden-xs hidden-sm rollover-images" data-display="control">
      <img data-display="basic" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses">
      <img data-display="hover" src="https://media.web.com/media/Y8GSIn508Nnh1Rs7F1VVK7xIERYvvg0T-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses">
    </figure>
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses">
  </a>
  <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" style="width: 40px;">&lt;</button>
</div>
```

**Here is what i am trying to add display none the second image in a href in aboove html
but its not working**

```
jQuery('button.slick-prev').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find("a img:eq( 2 )").attr("style", "display: none !important");
});
```

**Any thoughts ?**

Comment: I edited your question,and it seems that you have a redundant `<button>` tag, now you can check you code

Comment: there are 4 images in that anchor...which one exactly are you trying to hide?

Comment: the second one, which is below the whole figure tag.

Comment: ok, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

try below click event function.

```js
$('.slick-prev').on('click',function() {
  $(this).parent().find("figure img:eq(1)").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amlabel-div categoryp_productflag_image_615448">
  <a href="https://www.web.com/bat-wing-sunglasses-black.html">
    <img src="https://www.web.com/skin/frontend/web/web/images/category/wph.png" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses1">
    <figure class="hidden-xs hidden-sm rollover-images" data-display="control">
      <img data-display="basic" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses2">
      <img data-display="hover" src="https://media.web.com/media/Y8GSIn508Nnh1Rs7F1VVK7xIERYvvg0T-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses3">
    </figure>
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses4">
  </a>
  <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" style="width: 40px;">&lt;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working, but you are removing 3ed image because `.eg()` selector works as index starting at 0...

Also use [CSS selector >](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) to find siblings of `a` element and exclude `a's` in `figure`.

```
.parent().find("a > img:eq( 1 )")
```

And you should use `.css("...","...")` to add styles not `attr`

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```js
jQuery('button.slick-prev').click(function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().find("a > img:eq( 1 )").attr("style", "display: none !important");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amlabel-div categoryp_productflag_image_615448">
  <a href="https://www.web.com/bat-wing-sunglasses-black.html">
    <img src="https://www.web.com/skin/frontend/web/web/images/category/wph.png" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses1">
    <figure class="hidden-xs hidden-sm rollover-images" data-display="control">
      <img data-display="basic" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses2">
      <img data-display="hover" src="https://media.web.com/media/Y8GSIn508Nnh1Rs7F1VVK7xIERYvvg0T-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses3">
    </figure>
    <img class="visible-xs visible-sm" src="https://media.web.com/media/uU0gFAsQ67eMTBqvFm2PuG8ahps4GadG-32.jpg" width="460" height="580" alt="Batting My Lashes Sunglasses4">
  </a>
  <button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="previous" style="width: 40px;">&lt;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
// eq() is 0-based, so eq(1) will be second image, inside the <figure> tag
$('.slick-prev').parent().find('figure img').eq(1).css('display', 'none')
```